# Angular Route Resolves and Observables through child component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to make sense of using Observables in the Resolver state of my Angular app.

Here's the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/e9XMEKnW3uHjoWxxpUEZ?p=preview

I have an app where there is a sidebar on the left, where a list of items would be visible depending on the Route. The sidebar component is inside the root component's html.

```
<body>
    <articles-list [articles]="posts"></articles-list>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
```

On the right, we have the detail of each item. That component is loaded via Routes that have a Resolver to gather data from an API endpoint. I have the router-outlet inside of the root component.

```
// Routes
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "articles", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "articles",
    component: ArticleDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
    posts: ArticlesResolver
  }
];
```

I already have a setup working where the sidebar can successfully display a list of items coming from an API, but I cannot seem to access that list inside my Component Class and I'm trying to figure out why.

```
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() articles: any;
    resultsLength: Number;

    constructor() {
        // Both are undefined
        //this.resultsLength = this.articles.length;
        console.log(this.articles);
    }



    ngOnInit() {
        // Both are undefined
        //this.resultsLength = this.articles.length;
        console.log(this.articles);

    }
 }
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or something specific I should be doing to access the data? I'm trying to figure out why the observable is triggered even if the GET call is not done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
_articles: any;

@Input()
get articles(): any {
    return this._articles;
}
set articles(value: any) {
  this._articles = value;
}
```

By using a getter/setter it will get the value as it is updated. So after the Observable completes it will have the current value.

Comment: Thank you !!! Is there a way to also get the values through the ngOnInit? I updated the plunker and can see the value get updated, but the onInit method still returns undefined -> https://plnkr.co/edit/e9XMEKnW3uHjoWxxpUEZ?p=preview

Comment: I would guess that immediately when the component is initialized (in ngOnInit) that the value is not yet passed in, so will be undefined.If you need to write code  (like the resultsLength in your example), add it to the setter as you have. Or you can use the ngOnChanges event.